# Is it possible to edit and recompile a iOS kernel?

Tags: ios, iphone, kernel

I want to decompile a iOS 3.1.3 kernel to better understand it, but i'm not sure where to start, But don't be fooled i'm no green horn when it comes to programming.

Comment: This question is way too broad.

Comment: It's easy to criticize, but you could try instead giving more constructive criticism.

Comment: It's tempting to get defensive, but you could read the Stack Overflow [help file](http://stackoverflow.com/help). This site encourages asking specific technical questions that can produce definitive answers. If you can isolate some specific issue or problem, you're much more likely to receive assistance.

Answer (score 2):

The kernel is [open source](http://www.opensource.apple.com) so you can view and compile it. [iOS 3.1.3](http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/iphone-313/) is in the repo but you will also want to look at [3.0](http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/iphone-30/).

From [Apple](https://www.apple.com/opensource/):

> As the first major computer company to make Open Source development a key part of its ongoing software strategy, Apple remains committed to the Open Source development model. Major components of Mac OS X, including the UNIX core, are made available under Apple’s Open Source license, allowing developers and students to view source code, learn from it and submit suggestions and modifications.

Comment: As far as I know the iOS kernel is not open source.

Comment: @JosephFoote OK, what is it? You did check the link right? Cocoa and CocoaTouch are not open source.

Comment: Yep I checked the link, quote from Wikipedia "Source model    Closed source". Apple would not have the kernel as open source as that would compromise there security.

Comment: I updated the answer. Note: "allowing developers and students to view source code, learn from it and submit suggestions and modifications."

Comment: OS X maybe open source but the iOS kernel is not.

Comment: Actually you get security by not hiding the errors. This is how all the cryptographic primitives are done. Security is in the methods, not obscurity.

Comment: I personally know the OSX kernel is open source, I have written drivers for it.

Comment: OSX has FreeBSD as a base + the Mach kernel and portions of OSX have made their way back into FreeBSD. Darwin is the Unix-derived core that provides the underlying foundation for Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1):

The XNU kernel in its iOS incarnation is *not* open source, though xnu in its i386/x86_84 (and , for older versions PPC) is.

XNU is built up internally of several layers, with the bottom two - platform expert and ml_* APIs serving as the "glue" to the underlying hardware. This means that without said pieces you could compile the source (with an ARMv7 cross compiler, like the one in the iPhone SDK), but the kernel wouldn't actually boot.

Another difficulty is in the kernel extensions (XNU-speak for "modules"). These are drivers, without which you can't really do much - again, with the kernel not booting since it can't initialize any of its platform dependencies.

Also, contrary to how it may seem, though the iOS and OS X kernels are very similar, there are some subtle differences (which were visible by #ifdef CONFIG_EMBEDDED and #ifdef ARM until after 1699, when Apple realized they were leaking information of use to jailbreakers, and finally used a preprocessor to strip the iOS specific modifications before making it public.

Decompilation is a different matter. It's possible to disassemble and work back, from the kernel image (once decrypted or dumped) through fairly readable assembly (though not to a full source level). IDA and other specialized tools (e.g. jtool) have these capabilities.

There have been at least two projects to get the open source version to compile and boot for ARM. One by Christina Brooks(?) and another by WinOCM. The latter, which has gained notoriety for knowing XNU in its ARM implementation inside out, has eventually been employed by Apple, thereby reducing the chance of any open source implementation ever seeing the light of day.